# Determine end-of-file using Java's Scanner class

Tags: java, file, file-io, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read text from a text file. I need help figuring out when the end of file has occurred. How can I determine this in Java?

```
FileInputStream istream = new FileInputStream("\""+filename+"\"");      
Scanner input = new Scanner(istream);
while(EOF != true)
{
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 26):

You can check using `hasNextLine()`:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("\""+filename+"\""));
while(input.hasNextLine())
{
   String data = input.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: `Scanner.hasNextLLine()` will crash and burn if you're not reading an entire line at a time (`.nextLine()`).  Otherwise, per Thomas Langston, use `.hasNext()` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Line based retrieval may be what you want, but token based can also be useful.
You can see in documentation of [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

```
public boolean hasNext()
```

> Returns `true` if this `Scanner` has another token in its input. This method may block while waiting for input to scan. The `Scanner` does not advance past any input.
>
> Specified by:
>       `hasNext` in interface `Iterator<String>`
>
> Returns:
>       `true` if and only if this `Scanner` has another token
>
> Throws:
>       `IllegalStateException` - if this `Scanner` is closed
>
> See Also:
>       `Iterator`