# Java exception from scanning a file that was imported

Tags: java, import, java.util.scanner, file-import

I am trying to make a program that imports a text file and analyzes it to tell me if another text file has possible match up sentences. I keep running into this error when I import my file and attempt to analyze it. I am assuming that I am missing something in my code.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
at PossibleSentence.main(PossibleSentence.java:30)
```

Heres my code too:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class PossibleSentence {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{       
      Scanner testScan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Please enter the log file to analyze: ");
      String fileName = testScan.nextLine();

      File f = new File(fileName);
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
      String line = null;
      int i = 0;

      while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
         String word = scan.next();
         i++;
      }

      scan.close();

      File comparative = new File("IdentifyWords.java");
      Scanner compare = new Scanner(comparative);
      String line2 = null;
   }
}
```

The second scanner I havent completed yet either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which line is 30 exactly?

Comment: Hard to say, but it may be that the filename is wrong?

Comment: I believe its line 30 of the text file I am trying to read, thats where the text file stops, so i dont think that I am ending the scan correctly

Comment: @user2938612 no.  `at PossibleSentence.main(PossibleSentence.java:30)`  It says right there it's line 30 of `PossibleSentence`.  Which line is line 30?

Comment: @tieTYT it is the line "String word = scan.next();"

Comment: @dhappyman0 I'm no `Scanner` expert.  Perhaps check for `hasNext()` instead of `hasNextLine()` in that while loop.  If that doesn't work, show us the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need more info to conclusively answer, but check out [the documentation for next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29).  It throws this exception when there's no next element.  My guess is it's because of this part:

```
String fileName = testScan.nextLine();
```

You're not checking if `hasNextLine` first.

Comment: Scanner will throw and excetion if it encounters an eof(end of file) see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208502/how-to-determine-when-end-of-file-has-been-reached

Comment: I could do that, would that be effected though because I am inputting the name of the file that I want to analyze. Would that work in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a file argument to a `Scanner` object, try using an `InputStream`

```
File input = new File(/* file argument*/);
BufferedReader br = null;
FileReader fr= null;
Scanner scan = null;
try {
    fr = new FileReader(input);
    br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    scan = new Scanner(br);
    /* Do logic with scanner */
} catch (IOException e) {
    /* handling for errors*/
} finally {
    try {
        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
        if (fr != null) {
            fr.close();
        }
        if (scan != null) {
            scan.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        /* handle closing error */
    }
}
```

Comment: `Scanner` has a `File` constructor, it automatically wraps the file for you in an io stream : `this((ReadableByteChannel)(new FileInputStream(source).getChannel()));` (Scanner 656)

Comment: Then that would me something I did not know, not a frequent user of Scanner :)