# Check whether the line is the last one in the text document

Tags: java

I am trying to check whether I have reached the last line in the text document to write a simple line in the text document.

I have tried the following code below but I am getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

I have text in `hello.txt` document so I dont understand what this error mean.

How can I fix that?

I appreciate any help.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("D:\\hl_sv\\hello2.txt");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("D:\\hl_sv\\hello.txt")) {

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();

            // In the case the line is the last one and there is no number.
            // The content of the arrayList must be printed.
            if ((line = scanner.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("last line in the text document");
                writer.write("last line in the text document.");
            }

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**Edit**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("D:\\hl_sv\\hello2.txt");

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner("D:\\hl_sv\\hello.txt")) {
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();

                    // In the case the line is the last one and there is no number.
                    // The content of the arrayList must be printed.
                    if (line.isEmpty()) { // <-- Removed  = scanner.nextLine()
                        System.out.println("last line in the text document");
                        writer.write("last line in the text document.");
                    }else{
                        writer.write(line);
                    }

                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

With the edit code I am not getting the error anymore but I am getting this `D:\hl_sv\hello.txt` line printed in the text document `hello2.txt`?

Comment: This is a lot of unnecessary code for a simple task of appending text to the end of a file..

Comment: After editing the code did you get same exception?

Comment: There is no exception but the lines in the hello.txt are not being printed in the hello2.txt  except this line `D:\hl_sv\hello.txt` which is not part of my hello.txt document?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Updated***

I try this code in my computer and its working fine according to your specification.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File(
                    "../Test/src/com/hello2.txt"));

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("../Test/src/com/hello.txt"));
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine()+"\n";
                System.out.println(line);
                writer.write(line);
            }

            System.out.println("last line in the text document");
            writer.write("last line in the text document.");
            scanner.close();
            writer.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edited**

You should add `new File`

```
new PrintWriter(new File("D:\\hl_sv\\hello2.txt"));
```

and

```
new Scanner(new File("D:\\hl_sv\\hello.txt")));
```

Because `PritWriter` needs `File` as argument and `Scanner` needs `String` or `File` as argument. As you are using only a `String` in `Scanner ( "D:\\hl_sv\\hello.txt" )` thus you got "D:\hl_sv\hello.txt" line in hello2.txt file.

And you can use a `line` variable declared immediately after the main function to get access of `line` variable in main class.

So your code should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line="";

    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("D:\\hl_sv\\hello2.txt"));

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("D:\\hl_sv\\hello.txt"))) {

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();

            // In the case the line is the last one and there is no number.
            // The content of the arrayList must be printed.

        }

        System.out.println("last line in the text document");
        writer.write("last line in the text document.");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

You can check last line of that text file in very simple way / logic just do your operation after the `while` loop. Because after that while loop in your code there is no line in your text file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("D:\\hl_sv\\hello2.txt"));

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("D:\\hl_sv\\hello.txt"))) {

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();

            // In the case the line is the last one and there is no number.
            // The content of the arrayList must be printed.

        }

        System.out.println("last line in the text document");
        writer.write("last line in the text document.");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

When you using this statement

```
if ((line = scanner.nextLine()).isEmpty())
```

the `scanner` cannot find any line (after end of the file) so there is no such element (next line) exist so you got this exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Comment: I want to read the file and then write somthing at the end so I need the while statement.

Comment: Yes you can read a file and then write it in while loop. but you can do it also outside of the while loop. Because the file didn't closed

Comment: But if I do it outside the while loop then `line` vairable is unknown? Please can you modify your answer to text it with your way.

Comment: I again updated my answer and showing code which I tried in my computer and it's working to your specification. please check.

Comment: You have to add this line `writer.println(line);` to the while loop to print the lines of the hello.txt in the new one otherwise it works hanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the linked post for more information.

[How to determine when end of file has been reached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208502/how-to-determine-when-end-of-file-has-been-reached)

Basically the hasNextLine() function will tell you if you have reached the end of file (which you seem to be using already). I would say rearrange your loop slightly to incorporate this if you want it as a feature.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be executing the following

```
line = scanner.nextLine();
```

twice per loop.

Given that information, removing one of those calls will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're moving the scanner two lines every time because you call `.nextLine()` twice.

Fix:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("D:\\hl_sv\\hello2.txt");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("D:\\hl_sv\\hello.txt")) {

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();

            // In the case the line is the last one and there is no number.
            // The content of the arrayList must be printed.
            if (line.isEmpty()) { // <-- Removed  = scanner.nextLine()
                System.out.println("last line in the text document");
                writer.write("last line in the text document.");
            }

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply test `hasNextLine()`

```
        if ( ! scanner.hasNextLine() ) {
            System.out.println("last line in the text document");
            writer.write("last line in the text document.");
        }
```

A related, rather interesting topic is, if we use `Files.lines(path)`, which is a `Stream<String>`, how do we detect the last line :)