# Write line at the end of the text document

Tags: java

I am trying to write line at the end of my text document but nothing is being printed at the end of the `hello2.txt` with this code just the `hello.txt` is being printed. This line `last line in the text document.` is not being printed at the end of the `hello2.txt`. How can I fix that?

I appreciate any help.

**hello.txt**

```
I am at home
how are you brother?
I am facing problem
```

**hello2.txt** Should looks like this

```
I am at home
how are you brother?
I am facing problem
last line in the text document.
```

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("D:\\hl_sv\\hello.txt");
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("D:\\hl_sv\\hello2.txt");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();

            if (line.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("last line in the text document");
                writer.println("last line in the text document.");
            } else {
                writer.println(line);
            }

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont think you want to be using isEmpty() to check the last line.

Comment: @XorProgramming - this is not the same question, and not the same problem.

Comment: duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714916/check-whether-the-line-is-the-last-one-in-the-text-document/30715315#30715315

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the last line, `while (scanner.hasNextLine())` will be evaluated to false, those not entering the loop again, and not writing the last line. You need to add the line after the loop terminates.

Comment: @Tom - you're right, I'm not familiar with Java7 features enough. Thanks!

Comment: This is the good thing about the try-with-resources Statement ... we can't forget to close the resource properly :D.

Answer (score 2):

Also, because it looks like you want to append this line to the end of the text file, use:

```
writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(nameOfFile, true));
```

In fact, simply just use the writer.append(String) method in order to add the desired String at the end of the file.