# Java Reading Strings to a 2D Boolean Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to read a txt file which consists of # and spaces to a 2D boolean array, so that technically a # represents true and a space represents false.

With the help of similar posts i got together a code, although they were reading integers to an array.

My code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x;
    String y;
    Scanner fileName = null;
    try {
        fileName = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/USER/Desktop/hashtag.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    x = fileName.nextLine();
    y = fileName.nextLine();

    boolean[][] cells = new boolean[x][y];

    String finalX = fileName.nextLine();
    String finalY = fileName.nextLine();
    cells[finalX][finalY] = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++) {
            if (cells[i][j])
                System.out.print("#");
            else
                System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

In my code where I have written `boolean[][] cells = new boolean[x][y];`

It says the `[x]` and `[y]` requires an int, but found a string. The same issue is for `cells[finalX][finalY] = true;`

I tried parsing i.e. `Integer.parseInt(x)` however this gets me an error:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "#####################"`

At what point is my issue? If I parse to an Int, then it can't read the # correct?

Comment: Show us the content of `hashtag.txt`

Comment: what do you think ``new boolean[x][y]`` does when ``x`` and ``y`` are ``String``s?

Comment: @f1sh ah it tries to assign the size of the array? But can't since they are strings and not int?

Comment: @godlypython You're understanding what has happened.  Is the file guaranteed to be exactly 2 lines long?  If not, you may find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208502/how-to-determine-when-end-of-file-has-been-reached

Comment: `fileName.nextLine()` gives you a line of your txt file, i.e. a `String`. You can't use a `String` to initialize the dimensions of a 2D array. Use `string.length()` if you want to use the strings' length as the array dimensions.

Comment: No, I wanted it to read the whole file regardless of the amount of rows and columns.

Comment: what exactly the contents of the file , you didn't explain the pattern of info in the file.

Comment: you read only 2 lines does the file only contains 2 lines and how you distinguish between # and space.

Comment: @MohammadOghli i added an image for an example of what the file could be like.

Comment: Does my code only read 2 lines because the nextLine() isn't in a for loop?

Comment: @godlypython exactly. readLine() only reads one line per call.

Comment: @f1sh I surrounded the code in a `while(fileName.hasNextLine()) {` until the end of the for loop. But I receive an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds:21 at `cells[finalX.length()][finalY.length()] = true;` And I don't understand why if the loop continues till the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would solve it:

1- read each line of file until the end of it to get the number of cells rows which is `n` then take length of any String line to get number of columns which is `m`.

2- create boolean array `cells[n][m]`.

3- read file line by line and put each line in String variable and iterate over the string variable characters if character is `#` put `true` in cells array otherwise put `false`.

```
      String line="";
      int n=0;
      while(fileName.hasNextLine()){
        line = fileName.nextLine();
        n++;
      }
      int m = line.length();
      boolean[][] cells = new boolean[n][m];
      // initialize Scanner to read file again
      Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/USER/Desktop/hashtag.txt"));
      int i=0;
      while(in.hasNextLine()){
            line = in.nextLine();
        for(int j=0; j < line.length(); j++){
            char c = line.charAt(j);    
            if(c == '#'){
                cells[i][j] = true;
            }
            else{
                cells[i][j] = false;
            }
        }
        i++;
     }
```

Comment: @godlypython try this and i will put clarification of my code.

Comment: I will try this code, Does this mean I need two scanner inputs? one called fileName and the one u included as `in`

Comment: you need to initialize scanner to read file another time because when you read it first time you reach the end of file.

Comment: Yep i understand that. I made the code like this? https://pastebin.com/wik9kX0L it runs but I get a blank output.

Comment: you should try it on your console because the input file int C disk

Comment: also why you put `Scanner fileName = null;`

just put `Scanner fileName = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/USER/Desktop/hashtag.txt"));`

Comment: also this should be `Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/USER/Desktop/hashtag.txt"));`

Comment: Yeh I changed that, just had to remove my try catch statement. Hmm and what do you  mean by try on the console? I am running the Main method and it shows when  the process results? Im using IntelliJ

Comment: i mean don't try to compile code online because you read input file from your pc

Comment: Is it not printing because I dont have any System out println statement?

Comment: I put `System.out.println(line);` underneath i++ which worked too, is this also an approach since it is still within the loop and printing on a new line rather than creating another loop

Comment: you only need to print `#` and spaces based on cells array see my link.

Comment: if you find my answer useful accept it to be as reference in the future.

Comment: my algorithm is optimized as possible.

hope it help you.

Developer Mohammad

Answer (score 0):

> It says the [x] and [y] requires an int, but found a string. The same
>   issue is for cells[finalX][finalY] = true;
>
> I tried parsing i.e. Integer.parseInt(x) however this gets me an
>   error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For
>   input string: "#####################"

One approach you could do is first read the entire file.

Example:

```
List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();

while (fileName.hasNextLine()) {
     String line = fileName.nextLine();
     tempList.add(line);
}
```

then you can do this:

```
boolean[][] cells = new boolean[tempList.size()][tempList.get(0).length()];
```

**note** - this solution assumes the **length()** of each line is the same and the columns of each line is the same.

Also, why do you need to perform this outside the loop?

```
cells[finalX][finalY] = true;
```

you should remove that line and let the loop do all the work to determine what's `#` or `' '`. Also, your `if condition` doesn't seem to be doing the correct operation. Consider implementing this approach and then go on from there.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen OP has mentioned it has # and spaces, and i think regardless of the content as long as it's read as a String we should get the length() of it no?

Comment: Hmm yes but then i get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 21` at line 27 where line 27 is `cells[finalX.length()][finalY.length()] = true;`

Comment: If the number of rows and columns always be the same, then your answer might work.  If not, then you don't know the number of rows until you've hit the end of the file.  Conditional upvote on the basis that this is the best we might be able to do.

Comment: Do you mean like this: https://pastebin.com/BRkhV3Ky
In this attempt i get `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found`. Is that due to my while loop closing at the wrong time?

Comment: I commented out a few lines: https://pastebin.com/Y0xjdMPN
Now it executes but I get an empty output, but its scrolling. Meaning its detecting the file size but not printing the elements inside.

Answer (score 0):

You have many mistakes in code and this approach is definitely wrong, you don't even save values that you read from file inside array. Also this code is simply not how you do it, for reading files where you don't know length of file you want to use Lists where you don't need to specify number of elements that list will take(its possible to do get semi-working solution with arrays but there is no point of learning something that is simply wrong). Before even trying to work with files you should learn more basic things, you don't even initialize your arrays properly, you use string for size and index which is causing those issues you mentioned, another beginner mistake is trying to parse non-integer string to int(you are trying to convert ############ to int which is impossible, you can only use this if you know that string is an integer like 1 or 5 or 1000). 
So my answer to your question is to just go slowly and learn basics then add new stuff step by step instead just rushing with it.